# How to prove $1+(n+1)x \le (1+x)^{n+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality, exponential-function, binomial-theorem

How to prove that for every real number $x\geq0$ and every integer $n\geq0$
$$1+(n+1)x \le (1+x)^{n+1}.$$

I'm  trying with the geometric mean and arithmetic mean inequality, but I don't know what $x_1, x_2, ... $ to get to this.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to mention that $x_1, x_2, ...$ are positive!

Comment: Do you know the generalized formula for (a+b)^n? Try to factor it out and see what cancels

Comment: ooh, I see, thank you!

Comment: This is known as Bernouilli's inequality

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20Bernoulli's%20inequality%20(named,often%20employed%20in%20real%20analysis.&text=Bernoulli's%20inequality%20

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475309/proof-by-induction-of-bernoullis-inequality-1-xn-geq-1-nx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\geq0$ then by the binomial theorem
$$(1+x)^{n+1}=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}{k}x^n\geq\binom{n+1}{0}x^0+\binom{n+1}{1}x^1=1+(n+1)x.$$
If we allow $x<0$ then there exist counterexamples, such as $x=-4$, $n=2$.